# How to apply Dropout in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use the following code to tune the hyperparameters (hidden layers, hidden neurons, batch size, optimizer) of an ANN.

```
## Part 2 - Tuning the ANN
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
def build_regressor(hidden_nodes, hidden_layers, optimizer):
  regressor = Sequential()
  regressor.add(Dense(units = hidden_nodes, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 7))
  for layer_size in range(hidden_layers):
      regressor.add(Dense(hidden_nodes, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
  regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'linear'))
  regressor.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mse'])
  return regressor
regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn = build_regressor, epochs = 100)

# Create a dictionary of tuning parameters
parameters = {'hidden_nodes': list(range(2,101)), 'hidden_layers': [4,5,6,7], 'batch_size': [25,32], 'optimizer' : ['adam', 'nadam','RMSprop', 'adamax']}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = regressor, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 10, n_jobs = 4)

start = time.time()
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
end = time.time()
elapsed = (end - start)/3600
```

Now I want to add a droppout layer after each of the hidden layer like this:

```
regressor1 = Sequential()
regressor1.add(Dense(units = 41, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 7))
regressor1.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor1.add(Dense(units = 41, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
regressor1.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor1.add(Dense(units = 41, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
regressor1.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor1.add(Dense(units = 41, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
regressor1.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor1.add(Dense(units = 41, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
regressor1.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor1.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'linear'))
regressor1.compile(optimizer = 'nadam', loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mse'])
history = regressor1.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 25, epochs = 500, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), callbacks = [EarlyStopping(patience = 10)])
```

Is there a way to tune the number of dropout layers (the same number of hidden layers) and the dropout rates together with my current code?

Thank you so much in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution

https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/

Tip: I would suggest you you to look for similar models created by other people and play with the dropout values they've used this will save you a lot of time